# Reflection MethodAccessException

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection

I have a simple code in Silverlight:

```
public void temp()
{
    try
    {                
        WriteableBitmap obj = new WriteableBitmap(10, 10);

        //PropertyInfo pr = obb.GetType().GetProperty("Pixels");
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        Type typeofType = type.GetType();

        MethodInfo getPropMethod = typeofType.GetMethod("GetProperty", new Type[] { typeof(string) }); //get method info
        PropertyInfo pix1 = type.GetProperty("Pixels"); // first call - no exceptions
        PropertyInfo pix2 = (PropertyInfo)getPropMethod.Invoke(type, new object[] { "Pixels" }); // second call - MethodAccessException
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

First call of method GetProperty executed successfully and throw no exception.
But second call - methodInfo.Invoke throw the MethodAccessException - why this happens?

Exception and Stacktrace:

```
MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Type.GetProperty(System.String)' to access security critical method 'SilverlightApplication3.MainPage.temp()' failed.

in System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
in System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
in System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
in System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
in System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
in SilverlightApplication3.MainPage.temp()
```

Comment: Is your input always the same  `new object[] { "Pixels" }` for both calls?

Comment: I'll have to double check at work. A quick test in LinqPad works fine, so I wouldn't be surprised if there's an extra security check in Silverlight's reflection layer preventing this, or simply a small tweak in its available API. Could you post the full exception message and stack trace please?

Comment: Too long stack to put in comment, please see image http://gyazo.com/783c35f5765a4ad51039a7a3b3d3f275

Comment: Do not add question-related information in comments, please edit your question and update its content.

Comment: Chris Sinclair - yes you right, code working fine in console application, but not in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

reflection in Silverlight is limited to what is available at compile time, maybe the firs time you call the function the condition is satisfied, after the first call something changes and the reflection can't executed.

> In Silverlight, you cannot use reflection to access private types and
>   members. If the access level of a type or member would prevent you
>   from accessing it in statically compiled code, you cannot access it
>   dynamically by using reflection.

refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc(VS.95).aspx) for documentation

Comment: I add the first call to demonstrate that the function `GetProperty` is available in statically compiled code, if I will remove this call - nothing changed. Looks like there is some another restriction or bug in Silverlight.

Comment: @AlexScherbinin the first call doesn't demonstrate any such thing.  The security restriction applies to invoking methods via reflection, which you don't actually attempt until the second call.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a consequence of the strong security restrictions in the Silverlight/CoreCLR model.

The reflection methods (or their underlying implementations) I believe would be considered `SecurityCritical`. The reflection code you have now would seem to still satisfy this, but I believe this goes into a special case specifically disallowed (likely due to security concerns). Similar code using delegates and compile time references work fine in Silverlight, including all the various ways to invoke that delegate:

```
var getPropMethodDelegate = new Func<string, PropertyInfo>(obj.GetType().GetType().GetProperty);
getPropMethodDelegate("Pixels");
getPropMethodDelegate.Invoke("Pixels");
getPropMethodDelegate.DynamicInvoke("Pixels");
```

But the act of retrieving that same function and invoking it via reflection does not work. I would suspect that this is a special case. I can't find *specific* documentation indicating this (maybe it's an implication of something written [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233102%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), but the error message seems to indicate that using a `MethodInfo` to invoke security critical methods makes it treated as "Security transparent".

I don't know if there's a particular workaround and I don't know your *specific* case here. I would suggest perhaps avoiding using reflection to get `MethodInfo` objects for the `System.Type` reflection methods and simply use normal delegates. If you *must* have it dynamically determine what `System.Type` reflection method to use, then maybe put in a wrapper that based on the incoming method name returns a compile-time delegate reference instead. For example:

```
if (reflectionType == "GetProperty")
{
    var getPropertyInfoDelegate = new Func<string, PropertyInfo>(obj.GetType().GetType().GetProperty);
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = getPropertyInfoDelegate(propertyName);
}
```

Or at this point, just do it more directly:

```
if (reflectionType == "GetProperty")
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
}
```

You can do more work to simplify this (for example, put the routines in dictionaries for fast lookups), but for a Silverlight/CoreCLR context I don't know a way around this.